# $n$ couples $n$ hotel rooms $2n$ tickets to open the door find E(X^2)

Tags: probability

I have the following question:

In a trip of $n$ couples $n$ hotel rooms.

$2n$ tickets to open the rooms were given randomly between $2n$ people ($n$ couples).

Let $X$ the number of guests that receive the right ticket that open their door's room.

Find $E(X^2)$

I manage to find $E(X)$ which equals $2$

**This is what I did**

Using indicators

**Notice!** $E(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}I_i*I_j)$ means that i,j are couples there are $n$ couples in total.

$$E(X^{2})=E(\sum_{i=1}^{2n}I_i*I_i)+E(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}I_i*I_j)+E(\sum_{i\neq j}^{2n^2-3n}I_i*I_j) =2+(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{2n}*\frac{1}{2n-1})+(\sum_{i=1}^{2n^2-3n}\frac{2}{2n}*\frac{2}{2n-1})$$

**Explanation:**

We know E(x) and we know that $E(\sum_{i=1}^{2n}I_i*I_i)=E(x)=2$

$E(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}I_i*I_j)$ while i,j are couple both of them must receive the right key hence we get : $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{2n}*\frac{1}{2n-1})$

$E(\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}I_i*I_j)$ the total possibilities to order $2n$ people in pairs are $2n^2$ while we know we already calculated for each $I_i,I_j$ couples and $I_i,I_i$ therefore we decrease $3n$ from $2n^2$ and we get : $(\sum_{i=1}^{2n^{2}-3n}\frac{2}{2n}*\frac{2}{2n-1})$

My answer is not correct for some reason.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Not following your manipulations of the sums.  Seems like you just want to compute $\sum_{i\neq j}E[I_i\times I_j]$ no?  But that is easily done.   I don't understand where the $2n^2-3n$ comes from.

Comment: Yes I want to compute $E(X^2)$ which I know that is equal to $\sum_{i\neq j}E[I_i\times I_j]$ How is that easily done? I'm stuck for more than 2 hours on this question.

Comment: Well, for any one pair $i\neq j$ we have $E[I_i\times I_j]$ is just the probability that both $i,j$ receive the right key.  If they aren't roommates that's just $\frac 2{2n}\times \frac 2{2n-1}$.  If they are roommates it's $\frac 2{2n}\times \frac 1{2n-1}$.

Comment: @lulu This is exactly what I wrote yet I still don't get the right answer for $E(x^2)$

Comment: yeah, I agree that something's off.  My calculation gives an impossible answer for $n=1$.   In that case we know that both people get the right key and that the variance is $0$.  Hence $E[X^2]=E[X]^2=4$.  But somehow I am getting $5$. Must be counting wrong...

Comment: Ok, I see my error.  Of course each married couple counts twice.  Thus there are $2n$ married pairs and as there are $2n(2n-1)=4n^2-2n$ total pairs there are $4n^2-4n$ unmarried ones.  Thus the answer I get is that $E[X^2]=2+2n\times \left(\frac 2{2n}\times \frac 1{2n-1}\right)+(4n^2-4n)\times  \left(\frac 2{2n}\times \frac 2{2n-1}\right)=2+\frac {8n-6}{2n-1}$.  I am not 100% sure this is correct, but it at least gives the right answer when $n=1$.

Comment: Should say:  I am slightly surprised that it depends on $n$.  The equivalent question for the number of fixed points in a random permutation does not depend on $n$.    To be sure, intuition isn't really reliable here.

Comment: I only got the final answer which is $E(X^2)=6-\frac{2}{2n-1}$ and I have no idea how they manage to get there.

Comment: But of course that is equivalent to mine.  Both are $\frac {12n-8}{2n-1}$.  Take a look at my calculation.  It's the same as yours, essentially...I think that the tricky bit is to count the various pairs correctly.